# Can convolution be used to measure the difference between two sequences?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convolution

Say I have an infinite sequence $S_1$ and another finite sequence $S_2$.

If I calculate
$$ E = S_1 ∗ S_2 $$
does it somehow reflect whether $S_2$ appears somewhere in $S_1$?

What if an approximate version of $S_2$ does appear in $S_1$?

Comment: The output of a convolution is a sequence of inner-products, so you can apply the Cauchy-Schwartz inequality to them to measure similarity at that point in the convolution.

Comment: I should have added that what you are referring to is more commonly known as a [matched filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matched_filter).

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's exactly what I was looking for :)